# How to justify motivations for a second master?

Tags: masters, interview, software, germany, motivation

I have already graduate from a master degree in Europe (Software Engineering) , and applied for **another master degree** (Informatic) in Germany (TUM).

I have applied with my BSc. degree diploma and transcripts to the German university. My scores in bachelor is quit good, and convincing. The issue is they have invited me to an interview. I guess they want to know **why i am still motivated for another master, while i have one?**

Here are my motivations:

1. The focus of my first master was **Software engineering**, meanwhile now i am interested to learn about **distributed systems, networks**.
2. I am looking for a careers which needs both the  programming and network, and i think this master programme would help me. I am already good as a developer but i need to improve my skills in network.
3. I have some raw idea over the Bitcoin, Blockchain , and Internet of Things, and i need to be in touch with some experienced teachers who have deep knowledge in this fields.
4. Germany is an awesome country. I love the language and culture, and i think there are lot's of job opportunities for IT people.I have some basic command in German, and i am going to advance them during the programe.

**Do you think these motivations make sense for them?**

Answer (score 2):

I don't find your justification wise enough for a second master degree in distributed systems and networks. Moreover, I don't find a real target behind the second master degree other than getting associated with professors and the country.

If your prime purpose is to learn new stuff, you don't need a second academic degree which is very similar to the one that you already have. You can learn on your own. Moreover, you could directly apply for a research degree (say Ph.D.) in Germany instead. This would definitely make more sense. Unless you have some serious career goals to pursue on the specified courses, you should not do it. In my university, my colleagues who have Ph.D. in software engineering are now doing serious research in IoT, Distributed Systems, and Network security.

Ask yourself this question: *If you get interested in computational economics after 2 years, would you again apply for a masters degree in the same field?*

Comment: Do you mean i should change the primary purposes from 1 to 3?
if u want to justify it, what will you write?

Comment: @Salman The third point is even not okay. Consider you had a discussion that you have a raw idea on the problem, what if it does not work? What if it has already been explored? What if the university is not interested in that?

Comment: what is your solution for this interview? i cannot give up

Comment: @Salman Do you have a fully funded scholarship for the full course? If yes, then you speak with them about your possible career goal in the same field such as an extension to a research degree or a job in the equivalent area.

Comment: No. The university does not provide scholarship for any one in the first semester.

Comment: @Salman You could follow a related question here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2971/pursuing-a-second-masters-degreepart-time-pros-and-cons. Rest depends on you. We could only advise.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. You're passionate about the country, you are focussed on a particular career goal, and you feel that this Masters programme is what you need to take you down that path.

If they didn't accept that then I would be surprised.